# Xquery and empty tags

Tags: xml, html, xquery

I am using a rather old verision of exist at work. I'd love to update it, but unfortunately were are too small and I am to junior to get this done anytime in the next few months.

Anyway, I rewriting some document table of contents. I would like to output an empty span tag that has an icon, unforunately that is not working correctly.

#### Here is a brief snippet using Xquery 1.0

```
else if ( $section/name()= 'body') then
   <h3><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"></span>
    Body
    </h3>
```

This transforms to the following

#### HTML

```
<h3>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e"/>
    Body
</h3>
```

which is again misintrerpted by the browsers(chromium/firefox) I am testing in to the following:

```
<h3>
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">
     Body
    </span>
</h3>
```

The Text should not be wrapped in the span tag, it should precede it as an icon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980010/xslt-empty-tags

Comment: that was for `xslt`. I have solved this problem four months ago, but I do wonder if a similar solution can be proposed for `XQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exist but I'd try something like

```
<h3>
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">{" "}</span>
  Body
</h3>
```

or similar.  You might also look for some way to control the serialization globally.

Comment: i am thinking a long the same lines. I have made a few other modifications I am testing out first, but I put in a `#&160;` I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: well my `#&160;` did the trick, but I have to assume `{" "}` would've done the same. I just wish it didn't feel like a hack.