# How to prevent self closing tags as well empty tags after transforming

Tags: xslt, tags

I have in an input file:

```
<a></a>
<b/>
<c>text</c>
```

I need to converting this to string. Using transformer I am getting below output:

```
<a/> <!-- Empty tags should not collapse-->
<b/>
<c>text</c>
```

If I use xslt and output method is "HTML", I get the below output:

```
<a></a> <!-- This is as expected-->
<b></b> <!-- This is not expected-->
<c>text</c>
```

I want the structure same as in input file. It is required in my application since I need to calculate index and it will be very difficult to change the index calution logic.

What would be the correct XSLT to use?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get that fine a level of control with an XML/HTML processing tool (as opposed to a text processing tool) because `<a></a>` and `<a/>` (and `<a />` and any number of variations with whitespace within the tags) are identical as far as any XML/HTML parser is concerned.

Comment: Thanks Roberts but my concern is not about the white spaces in the tags, I just want that my input should be the same as output after using Transforming ie If tags are <a></a> it should remain <a></a> and if they are <b/> in input it should remain as it is in the output which is not the case using Transformation. One more thing I just have document object so need to use Transformation to convert it to string is there any other way out???

Comment: I don't think XSLT can solve that then as its data model for both `<a/>` as well as `<a></a>` will simply contain an `a` element node with no attributes and no child node. The markup is not present in the data model and can thus not be preserved when serializing a tree back to markup.

Comment: ohk so any alternate solutions to convert document object to string without using Transformation ?

Comment: The information about whether the original XML contained `<a/>` or `<a></a>` will have been lost at the point where it was parsed to create the `Document` object.  If you care about this level of detail then you're not processing XML, you're processing text that happens to contain some `<>` characters and you should probably use text processing tools rather than an XML tree object model.

Comment: @Vix, what platform do you use? There are tree models that store that information, for instance the DOM implementation in the .NET framework has http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.isempty.aspx. So look at tree models for the programming platform you use whether the element node representation provides such information.

Comment: @Martin, Java. 
My only concern is how do I get the complete `Document` contents in a string without any modification of original. Earlier I used Transform Factory which seems to be quick and easy but not solving my purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT Empty Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980010/xslt-empty-tags)

Answer (score 0):

What XSLT processor? XSLT is merely a language to transform xml so "html output" is dependent on the processor.

I'm going to guess this first solution is too simple for you but i've had to use this to avoid processing raw html

```
<xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />
```

as this should clone the raw input.
In my case, I have used the following to extract all nodes that had the raw attribute:

```
<xsl:for-each select="xmlData//node()[@raw]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Other options:

2) Add an attribute to each empty node depending on what you want it to do later ie role="long", role="short-hand".

3)
Loop through each node (xsl:for-each)

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length(.)=0"> <!-- There is no child-->
<xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
...whatever normal processing you have
</xsl:otherwise>
```

4) Redefine your problem. Both are valid XHTML/XML, so perhaps your problem can be reframed or fixed elsewhere.

Either way, you may want to add more information in your question so that we can reproduce your problem and test it locally.

P.S. Too much text/code to put in a comment, but that's where this would belong.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is to use disable-output-escaping like this:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;a&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</xsl:text>
```

But I understand that this is a dirty solution...