# Blade/Laravel - prevent self closing tags in markup templating

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to have a block of html wrapped in an anchor if a certain condition is met. The code looks like this:

```
@if($rs->meta['first_name'] == "MyFirstName")
<a href="/url-to-page">
@endif
<!-- HTML Markup Here -->
@if($rs->meta['first_name'] == "MyFirstName")
</a>
@endif
```

The `a` tags have a CSS of:

`a {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

What's happening is the `a` tags are self closing breaking the page. It outputs:

```
<a href="/url-to-page"></a>
<a href="/url-to-page">
<!-- HTML Markup Here -->
</a>
```

It needs to just output:

```
<a href="/url-to-page">
<!-- HTML Markup Here -->
</a>
```

I did research and all I found: [How to prevent self closing tags as well empty tags after transforming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956964/how-to-prevent-self-closing-tags-as-well-empty-tags-after-transforming) - NOT XSLT, so not a duplicate and relevant to my situation.

How do I wrap components in anchor tags in blade templating and not have it self close?

Comment: Well, I maybe wrong, and this may not be the answer you were looking for, but from the look of that structure, you are trying to apply the link to everything (html markup) in between, so basically everything is relying on first_name being "My First Name". In that case you did not need to close the first if, and there is no need for the second if. Am I making sense?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: also wth can someone explain why this got downvoted?

Comment: What are you trying to put into the `<a>` element? I'd bet it's not allowed.

Comment: I'd also bet that isn't what "it outputs" but rather what you see when you use your browser's inspector. View source to see what the PHP is actually outputting.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379407/2797224) may help.

Answer (score 0):

How about just printing the a tag anyways but not populating its href attribute? Like this:

```
<a 
@if($rs->meta['first_name'] == "MyFirstName")
    href="/url-to-page" 
@endif >
<!-- HTML Markup Here -->
</a>
```

If the a tag doesn't have href attribute it will just render its content afaik.
Let me know if the answer is satisfying or not.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of your issue is because of the two if statements. Why do you need them?

Ok, Looking back at your code, I better understand what it is that you are trying to accomplish...
The issue is the two if statements. You only need one if statement. Try something like this and you will get the results you are looking for.

```
@if($rs->meta['first_name'] == "MyFirstName")
<a href="/url-to-page">

<!-- HTML Markup Here -->
</a>
@endif
```

Notice that what I done was removed the one if. So, if your condition is met, then the HTML Markup is displayed as your anchor text and then finally the a is closed. All of this happens inside of one if statement though.
The if checks the condition and if it is true, then it will render the a as well as all of the HTML markup that you have before the endif.

Comment: because I need wrap the entire HTML block in an anchor for that one specific instance of the index of thr loop

Comment: Your logic is all wrong in that. You are checking the same thing in both if statements. So, you should do away with the two and use only one, placing the needed HTML block inside that one. Then make sure you are including anchor text to display on the page.

Comment: Presumably, OP wants the rest of the HTML displayed in both cases.

Comment: @miken32, But what are both cases? The way I read the code, he is checking the same thing in both If statements...@if($rs->meta['first_name'] == "MyFirstName"), so both cases are the same. However, I think his real issue is that he is not using any anchor text. So, there is nothing to display on the page.

Comment: I'd expect that `<!-- HTML Markup Here -->` represents some HTML markup there, that would be displayed regardless of the condition.

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with having an empty element. You can view source and see one right on this page. `<a name="tab-top"></a>`

Comment: I agree. But if he wants the link to display, then it has to have text. That was the point I was making. If he is concerned not about the link displaying, but rather that the link somewhat repeats itself, then that is because of how he has the two if statements. The a doesn't close until after the second if statement. So, naturally everything in between is going to show as anchor text. He either has to remove the second if or close the a before his html markup. No way around that.