# self closing tags issue on XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am using bellow XSLT syntax to select some values in my XML file and create a different version of XML file,

```
<xsl:element name="FirstName">
  <xsl:value-of select="//Invoice//FirstName"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Problem i am having here is when there is any empty values  within my XML  , my out put XML generates like below

```
<Invoice>
 <FirstName /> 
</Invoice>
```

I wanted to generate my XML file like below when there is an empty value

```
<Invoice>
 <FirstName>   </FirstName> 
</Invoice>
```

how do i do this in XSLT ?
thanks

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980010/xslt-empty-tags. Beware that you can be downvoted for posting questions without trying to search similar topics here at SO first ))

Comment: <xsl:output method="html">    didn't work for me, as i am using c#.Net to pass my XML file with XSLT to generate my new XML file.

Comment: I do not see relation between C# and xsl:output. Do you say that you added xsl:output="html" and it worked the same? Or did you get some sort of error? If the issue relates to the XSLT transformer (I mean it may be a particular XSLT transformer issue), then you probably can use some other one. I'm not good in C#. In Java there're at lest few of XSLT transformers available

Comment: The `FirstName` element in your requested output example is _not_ empty - it contains three characters, all spaces.

Comment: Have you tried xsl:output method="xhtml"? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413641/1028256

Comment: ah that's doesn't really matter. as long as stop being self closing.

Comment: visual studio only allows  html, text or xml only

Comment: `method="xhtml"` requires XSLT 2.0, .Net only supports 1.0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

XML:

```
<root>
<name>
<FirstName>Kishan</FirstName>
<LastName>Kumar</LastName>
</name>

<name>
<FirstName></FirstName>
<LastName>Raj</LastName>
</name>
 </root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FirstName">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(.) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:element name="FirstName">
                      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="FirstName">
                      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OutPut:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <name>
      <FirstName>Kishan</FirstName>
      <LastName>Kumar</LastName>
   </name>
   <name>
      <FirstName> </FirstName>
      <LastName>Raj</LastName>
   </name>
</root>
```

Comment: This solution is already described in the link I provided in comments above: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980010/xslt-empty-tags

Answer (score 3):

You could output a comment, as in

```
<xsl:comment/><xsl:value-of select="//Inoivce/FirstName"/>
```

This will result in output such as

```
<FirstName><!-- --></FirstName>
```

which should work just fine downstream.

This technique is sometimes used to force `script` tags to be non-closing, as they need to be:

```
<script src="foo.js"><xsl:comment/></script>
```